# Printing numbers in a dictionary inside a dictionary by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to print numbers in a dictionary inside a dictionary:

```
frame = ['frame1', 'frame2', 'frame3', 'frame4', 'frame5', 'frame6']
dx = [12, 34, 55, 66, 78, 65, 56, 234, 876, 999, 345, 945]
pd = ['pd1', 'pd2']

data = {}
dt = {}
k=0
for i in pd :
    dt[i] = []
    for j in frame :
        data[j] = dt
        data[j][i] = dx[k]
        k+=1
```

For this code it only retains the last values:

```
{'frame1': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}, 'frame2': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}, 'frame3': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}, 'frame4': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}, 'frame5': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}, 'frame6': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}}
```

This is the result I want:

```
{'frame1': {'pd1': 12, 'pd2': 56}, 'frame2': {'pd1': 34, 'pd2': 234}, 'frame3': {'pd1': 55, 'pd2': 876}, 'frame4': {'pd1': 66, 'pd2': 999}, 'frame5': {'pd1': 78, 'pd2': 345}, 'frame6': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
data = {}
k=0
for i in pd:
    for j in frame :
        # use setdefault to initialize inner dictionary
        data.setdefault(j, {})[i] = dx[k]
        k+=1
data
{'frame1': {'pd1': 12, 'pd2': 56},
 'frame2': {'pd1': 34, 'pd2': 234},
 'frame3': {'pd1': 55, 'pd2': 876},
 'frame4': {'pd1': 66, 'pd2': 999},
 'frame5': {'pd1': 78, 'pd2': 345},
 'frame6': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's some shared memory across all the dictionaries.

You can construct the dictionary using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
{f: dict(zip(pd, vals)) for f, vals in zip(frame, zip(dx[:len(dx)//2], dx[len(dx)//2:]))}
```

This outputs:

```py
{
 'frame1': {'pd1': 12, 'pd2': 56}, 'frame2': {'pd1': 34, 'pd2': 234}, 
 'frame3': {'pd1': 55, 'pd2': 876}, 'frame4': {'pd1': 66, 'pd2': 999}, 
 'frame5': {'pd1': 78, 'pd2': 345}, 'frame6': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from a nested dictionary comperhension, but it is a bit long:

```
{f: d for f, d in zip(frame, {pd[0]: i, pd[1]: j} for i, j in zip(dx[:len(frame)], dx[len(frame):]))}
```

A little simplification:

```
dict(zip(frame, (dict(zip(pd, x)) for x in zip(dx[:len(frame)], dx[len(frame):]))))
```

Output:

```
{'frame1': {'pd1': 12, 'pd2': 56},
 'frame2': {'pd1': 34, 'pd2': 234},
 'frame3': {'pd1': 55, 'pd2': 876},
 'frame4': {'pd1': 66, 'pd2': 999},
 'frame5': {'pd1': 78, 'pd2': 345},
 'frame6': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're resetting `dt` over every iteration of your outer for-loop. To get your desired output, just do this

```
for i in pd:
    for j in frame:
        if j not in data:
            data[j] = dict()
        data[j][i] = dx[k]
        k += 1
```

You can compress this into a list comprehension like this:

```
data = {f: {p: dx[j * len(frame) + i] for j, p in enumerate(pd)} for i, f in enumerate(frame)}
```

This compression iterates over `frames` and, for each item in `frames`, iterates over `pd`. For each item in `pd`, we then add items to a dictionary when we then add to the larger dictionary. The value of `dx` added to the dictionary is based on the jth entry of `pd` and the ith entry of `frames`.

Answer (score 1):

Better variable names help track what is going on.  Readability counts vs. one-liner list comprehensions.  The original code was inserting the same modified dictionary in each frame.

```py
from pprint import pprint

frames = ['frame1', 'frame2', 'frame3', 'frame4', 'frame5', 'frame6']
dx = [12, 34, 55, 66, 78, 65, 56, 234, 876, 999, 345, 945]
pds = ['pd1', 'pd2']

# Initialize each frame with a *different* empty dictionary
data = {frame:{} for frame in frames}

# Distribute dx across the frames and pds:
idx = iter(dx)
for pd in pds:
    for frame in frames:
        data[frame][pd] = next(idx)

pprint(data)
```

Output:

```py
{'frame1': {'pd1': 12, 'pd2': 56},
 'frame2': {'pd1': 34, 'pd2': 234},
 'frame3': {'pd1': 55, 'pd2': 876},
 'frame4': {'pd1': 66, 'pd2': 999},
 'frame5': {'pd1': 78, 'pd2': 345},
 'frame6': {'pd1': 65, 'pd2': 945}}
```